# Keyboard acting weird (c,v and h randomly stop working, windows key randomly stuck, ..)

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

A couple of weeks ago my keyboard started acting weird.

Randomly but only for one application (i think it only happens to Chrome), the keys c v and h will stop working. They would still work in other applications though. I have to restart the application to get all the keys to work again.

Another problem is the windows key being randomly stucked. I have to "switch user" and get back into my session to reset the windows key.

Last problem happens only to "Sublime Text 2". Suddenly, only the arrow keys would work. I can't edit anything, can't click on anything. Other applications would still work though. For that problem I have no solution but to restart the computer.

I absolutely don't know what cause these problems but I'm pretty sure they all appeared around the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a wireless keyboard, replace batts and re sync. 
If it is a desktop keyboard, try using it on another computer to see if the problems persists to the next machine. If so, buy a new keyboard. 
If it a laptop keyboard, sounds like a liquid spill try wiping it down with a baby wipe. 
Last an less likely malware is intercepting keystrokes and not doing a good job of it.
Good Luck